# Ecplise "mark occurrences" in HTML editor

Tags: eclipse

I wonder why the option "mark occurrences" isn't available (the button is grayed-inactive) when editing HTML files (*.html, *.htm extension). Is there an option to enable this feature in HTML editor in Ecplise (i'm running Eclipse Mars.2)?

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem with Aptana's HTML editor, and was finally able to resolve the issue.

First check to make sure this option is selected (by Default in Aptana for HTML, it is not). Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio ->Editors -> HTML. The very first option needs to be checked: "Mark occurrences with background color".

If the above did not work, you could try checking to see if you also have an additional installed software in Aptana that might be causing a conflict (this is actually what corrected my issue). I did have an additional software program added to aptana (called "Colorer"), which unbeknownst to me was disabling this functionality. If you have similar add-ins added to your installation, and they are not crucial to your workflow, I suggest removing them if the first option did not fix your issue.  Once I removed my add-in, my Mark Occurrences for HTML (and CSS) came back to life.